Is there an n8n default structure to have a main node and several action nodes inside of it?
I have this n8n custom node, let's call it company. When I search for company on the node panel the two action nodes that I already have show up (called authenticate and upload file). My problem is that when I select either one of them I have the dropdown on the top allowing me to select the action node. Image to show:

What I want is this flow, used by S3 for example. All suggestions I get are for having 2 core nodes, like (Company Authenticate and Company Upload File), which doesn't really make much sense.
Here is my main.node.ts (for the authentication and such)and respective package.json.
package.json nodes
   "nodes": {
      "main": [
        "dist/nodes/main/authenticate.node.js",
        "dist/nodes/main/uploadFile.node.js"
      ]
    }


export class Company implements INodeType {
  description: INodeTypeDescription = {
    displayName: 'Company',
    name: 'Company',
    icon: 'file:Company.png',
    group: ['transform'],
    version: 1,
    description: 'Create a project and translate a file in this node.',
    defaults: {
      name: 'Company',
      color: '#4B8BBE',
    },
    inputs: ['main'],
    outputs: ['main'],
    properties: [
      {
        displayName: 'Operation',
        name: 'operation',
        type: 'options',
        options: [
          {
            displayName: 'Authenticate',
            name: 'Authenticate',
            value: 'Authenticate',
            description: 'Authenticate your account',
          },
          {
            displayName: 'Upload File',
            name: 'uploadFile',
            value: 'uploadFile',
            description: 'Upload a file in Company',
          },
        ],
        default: 'Authenticate',
        description: 'Select the operation',
      },
      {
        displayName: 'Username',
        name: 'username',
        type: 'string',
        default: '',
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['Authenticate'],
          },
        },
        description: 'The username for authentication',
        required: true,
      },
      {
        displayName: 'Password',
        name: 'password',
        type: 'string',
        typeOptions: {
          password: true,
        },
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['Authenticate'],
          },
        },
        default: '',
        description: 'The password for authentication',
        required: true,
      },
      {
        displayName: 'Project Name',
        name: 'projectName',
        type: 'string',
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['uploadFile'],
          },
        },
        default: '',
        description: 'Name of the project to create.',
      },
      {
        displayName: 'Source Language',
        name: 'sourceLanguage',
        type: 'string',
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['uploadFile'],
          },
        },
        default: '',
        description: 'Source language of the project.',
      },
      {
        displayName: 'Target Language',
        name: 'targetLanguage',
        type: 'string',
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['uploadFile'],
          },
        },
        default: '',
        description: 'Target language of the project.',
      },
      {
        displayName: 'File Input',
        name: 'fileInput',
        type: 'string',
        displayOptions: {
          show: {
            operation: ['uploadFile'],
          },
        },
        default: '',
        placeholder: 'Select file...',
        typeOptions: {
          multipleValues: false,
          multipleValueButtonText: 'Add File',
        },
        required: true,
        description: 'The file to be processed.',
      },
    ],
  };

I have tried creating 2 nodes, called auth.node.ts and upload.node.ts and add them to the nodes in the package.json, but that just created 2 core nodes as I previously mentioned.
